# validate data using map function

Tags: vue.js

I would like to validate data using map.I would like to get the key name and check some conditions

```
const obj = {
    firstName: ['errorFirstName', 'msgFirstName'],
    lastName: ['errorLastName', 'msgLastName'],
    middleName: ['errorMiddleName', 'msgMiddleName'],
  }
  if (Object.keys(obj).includes(field)) {
 //I would like to pass here the object key length for each key :example if(this.firstName.length === 0)
    if(this[obj[key]].length === 0) {
      const [hasError, msg] = obj[field];
      this[hasError] = true;
      this[msg] = `${field} is required.`;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the key `field` to retrieve the value from your object:

```
const obj = {
  firstName: ['errorFirstName', 'msgFirstName'],
  lastName: ['errorLastName', 'msgLastName'],
  middleName: ['errorMiddleName', 'msgMiddleName'],
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(fieldName => {
  if (this[fieldName].length === 0) {
    // your logic here
    const [hasError, msg] = obj[fieldName];
    this[hasError] = true;
    this[msg] = `${fieldName} is required.`;
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to loop through all key field not only first name.Sorry i probably didn't explain it right.

Comment: That was a typo do you understand better the snippet now?

Comment: This is not returning this.firstName.length or this.lastName.length.I would like to get the key name with this keyword and get the length

Comment: Because each field yelds an array, which length do you want to check? The length of the array or the length of the second element in the array?

Comment: i would like to get the key.I don't want the length of the array.Just the key so i can write this.[key].length or this.firstName.length.I have firstName defined as variable.

Comment: Right, I understand better what you try to do here, check my updated answer. You were actually pretty close to the solution in your question. You just had to get rid of the dot before the square brackets.

Comment: if i print console.log(field) its returning firstName,lastName,middleName but when i use console.log(this[field] ) its returning an object instead of this.firstName

Comment: Well it turned out the error was also that you used `includes` instead of `forEach` I tested my last correction and it should work fine. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, don't forget to validate the question please!

Comment: How do u validate.I accepted the answer

Comment: I meant accept, sorry. That's perfect if you upvoted it too, cheers!